# Controller as ascx factory - bad idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, factory-pattern, renderaction

I'm trying to create something like *.ascxs' factory.

Scenario:
I would like to render controls which depends on model, which i've passed to partialView.
I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyAbstractModel>" %>

    <%= Model.Property1 %>
<!-- other more sophisticated displays on model -->

    <% Html.RenderAction("RenderControl", "Factory", new { model = Model});  %>
```

FactoryController:

```
public ActionResult RenderControl(object model) {
    if (model.GetType() == typeof(Model1) {
        return RenderPartial("Partial2", model);
    } else {
        return RenderPartial("Partial1", model);
    }
}
```

I'd like to know is there any better way to cope with such situation. I suppose It's not the most efficient method to build web page in ASP.MVC 2.

If this method is acceptable, how can i restrict access to such controller? I would like to use this class only on server side and only by ascxs' pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ChildActionOnly()` attribute to restrict access to your actions.

What you are trying to do is already builtin to MVC: `Html.DisplayFor()`

See: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html